# Sharepoint and Dynamix

Tags: sharepoint, axapta, business-connector

I have created a Sharepoint Timer Job in order to sync Sharepoint List with my database. I use Microsoft Dynamics Business Connector to update the database.

However when I run the SP Timer Job I get an error stating:

> The requested operation could not be performed as the user is not logged on to Dynamics

The code I used to connect to Dynamics is working fine in an aspx page.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Which version of AX and Sharepoint?

Comment: Make sure the app pool account with which SharePoint is running is authorized to connect to Dynamix